# A good solution for displaying galleries with lytebox and php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, gallery

I have thought for a while over an issue with the loading of images on a website-solution that I have programmed (For fun and the experience)

**The programming language** used is **PHP** with **MYSQL** as the database language
It also uses **javascript**, but not extensively

I have recently realized that the engine I programmed, while it has it's smart solutions also carry a lot of flaws and redundant code. I have therefore decided to make a new one, now incorporating what I know, but didn't when I started the previous project.

For the new system, there will be an option to add galleries to a site, and upload images to it. I have used the javascript image viewer Lytebox before. The screen goes dark and an image appears with a "Previous" and "next" button to view the other images.

**The problem** is that I used groups with lytebox and the images themselves, resized as thumbs. This causes lytebox to work only when all the images have loaded. If you click a link before that, the image is shown as if you right click and choose "Show image"

Information about these images is parsed from a database using a while statement with a counter that goes from 0 to sizeof()

I'm thinking it probably isn't a good idea to have the images as the thumbs, even if you restrict the upload size. Likewise, adding thumbs at upload also seems like a hassle. It would be practical if the thumbs didn't show up before they were fully loaded.

Has anyone got any good tips. Any help would be appreciated.

*Johann*

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not sure what your question is? Can you clarify? Are you looking to change lytebox's behaviour?

Comment: Hello.

Not really. What I would like to know is what route to go when creating a page that lets you upload images. Does other systems usually create thumbs-files when a user uploads a file? Is there a way to display images on the server as thumbs that doesn't require you to load the entire image?

What would also work would be to get lytebox to pop up, with a white frame and "wait" for the image. Basically everything else than opening the image as a regular link.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. What I would like to know is what route to go when creating a page that lets you upload images. Does other systems usually create thumbs-files when a user uploads a file? Is there a way to display images on the server as thumbs that doesn't require you to load the entire image?

What would also work would be to get lytebox to pop up, with a white frame and "wait" for the image. Basically everything else than opening the image as a regular link.

I had an account here before, seems like it has been reset or something. Tried logging on with both google open-ids. Wouldn't let me comment your comment so I had to do it the hard way and answer my own post :|